# How can I clone, edit & use a 3rd party Laravel plugin

Tags: laravel, github, composer-php

I have scoured the web for hours but I can not seem to wrap my head around this. I am developing a Laravel project where I am using the dependency UniSharp/laravel-settings. However, I have noticed that after upgrading my Laravel version to 6.0, the package breaks. I have figured out what I need to do to make the package work with Laravel 6.0 and now I wish to make the required changes and then use the modified package.

So far, I have cloned the original repository into my own (i.e realnsleo/laravel-settings) and I have cloned it onto my development machine. The trouble is, I don't know how to test whether my changes work. Do I need to setup a fresh Laravel installation to test the package? I noticed the package has it's own composer.json file, should I install those dependencies separate from the installed Laravel project? I am highly confused.

Can someone assist me with a step by step on what I need to do to achieve this? I will highly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: You're using an abandoned plugin. Less than 100 commits and last one was over a year ago. From what I'm seeing, everything this package does you can do with the cache facade.

Comment: The package's composer.json dictates its dependencies and most likely why you can't install it in your own repo. If you don't think the package is ever going to update, you might try to hack the dependencies to work with Laravel 6 but that can have a lot of unforeseen consequences. Cut your losses and just remove every trace of this from your project.

Comment: You're right. Time to cut my losses and find an alternative. Thank you all.